# how to use order by union queries in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

please let us know how to use order by clause in sql union query

**My query**

```
   select  receiverid as new_id, time from messenger where senderid= '".$_SESSION['id']."'
    UNION
  select senderid, time  from messenger where receiverid  = '".$_SESSION['id']."'
```

**i need exactly  Order by time Desc**

Please help us I have tried many ways but not working.. Thank you in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @CforCODE . . . Although this is marked as a duplicate, the accepted answer is simply more complicated than unnecessary.  I'm pondering whether I should reopen this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the duplicate link contains many answers one of which is the same as the one you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select receiverid as new_id
from messenger
where senderid= '".$_SESSION['id']."'
union
select senderid 
from messenger
where receiverid  = '".$_SESSION['id]
order by new_id;
```

More importantly, you don't need `union`.  Just use:

```
select distinct (case when receiverid = ? then senderid else receiverid) as id
from messenger m
where ? in (receiverid, senderid)
order by id;
```

And the most important part here is **using parameters**.  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.

Comment: I think that will only order the second `SELECT`, not everything.

Comment: @Barmar . . . It works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f29f7255a41a023b0c1c560b5bf20979.  Further, to order the individual `select`s, I know that you need parentheses.  This is in contract to SQL Server, where a subquery *is* necessary to order unions.

Comment: OK, I frequently get confused about whether it applies to the last query or the whole union.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  tq sir

Answer (score -1):

If you want to order the final result, you need to put the `UNION` in a subquery.

And you need to select the column that you want to order by.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select  receiverid as new_id, time  from messenger where senderid= '".$_SESSION['id']."'
    UNION
    select senderid, time  from messenger where receiverid  = '".$_SESSION['id']."'
) AS x
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: sir Not working this

Comment: query ok  but i need order by time ... please let us know

Comment: You should update the question to explain what you need to order by. I've updatd the answer.

Comment: yes sir exactly i have tried like you have updated query... but not working

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I'm pretty sure this should work.

Comment: see sir my updated query